# clientside_callback is throwing an error when page opens, but not when the page is refreshed

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a clientside_callback to get the width of the window whenever a dropdown value is changed:

```
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(a,b,c) {
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        return w;
    }
    """,
    Output('x_pixels', 'children'),
    Input('x', 'value'),
    Input('y', 'value'),
    Input('z', 'value'),
```

Which updates a html.Div:

```
html.Div([
        html.Div(id='x_pixels')
    ], style={'display': 'none'})
```

Which is throwing an error `dc[namespace][function_name] is undefined`. However, the strange thing is this doesn't always happens, it happens only around 90% of the time, and once the browser window and dash app is refreshed, the error doesn't appear when it has reloaded.

Any tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have other client side callbacks or just this one?

Comment: This is the only one

Comment: Hmm I'm not able to reproduce this one personally. I'd try asking on the plotly forums as well https://community.plotly.com/.